# Difference between $attributes and $classes in Drupal theming?

Tags: drupal-theming

In a panels TPL file I have the following, however this prints the classes out twice.

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $id; ?> <?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

Is there a difference between this:

```
class="<?php print $classes; ?>"
```

and this?:

```
<?php print $attributes; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, `class="<?php print $classes; ?>"`, only prints the classes for the class attribute in the element, while the `<?php print $attributes; ?>` prints all the attributes for that element: class, style, value, style, custom attrs like "tag" or "visibility", etc...

So you print classes with both functions. Use the `print $classes` if you only want to print classes, and `print $attributes` if you want to print all item attributes, including classes.